# ISO Duration Format validation in java

Tags: java, regex, string, format, duration

I googled but not able to find any good solution which will validate the input string is correct for [ISO Duration Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), if any one has any idea or solution may be using regexp or function, will help a lot.

Note: The format for a duration is `[-]P[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n][.frac_secs]S` where n specifies the value of the element (for example, 4H is 4 hours). This represents a subset of the ISO duration format and any other duration letters (including valid ISO letters such as Y and M) result in an error.

```
Example 1,
input string = "P100DT4H23M59S";
expected output = 100 04:23:59.000000

Example 2,
input string = "P2MT12H";
expected output = error, because the month designator, '2M', isn't allowed.

Example 3,
input string = "100 04:23:59";
expected output = 100 04:23:59.000000
```

.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36319272/3832970?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I want to validate only the input string not to convert

Comment: You wrote *input string = "P100DT4H23M59S"; expected output = 100 04:23:59.000000* - that is conversion, isn't it?

Comment: @subodh if it doesn't parse then it's invalid, no?

Comment: [Something like this](https://regex101.com/r/mB4iY9/1) ?

Comment: Thanks all, it works.

Comment: @RC. any idea how to implement the same in java 7

Comment: Take a look at joda-time, if you have to stick to java7

Answer (score 2):

## `java.time.Duration`

The *java.time* classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating text.

Use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

Call [`Duration#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) method. Trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) being thrown when encountering faulty input.

```java
String input = "P100DT4H23M59S";
try
{
    Duration duration = Duration.parse( input );
}
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Faulty input." );
}
```

The `Duration` class in Java represents a span-of-time unattached to the timeline on the scale of generic 24-hour days (not calendar days), hours, minutes, and seconds. (For calendar days, see [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) class.)

So your undesired inputs of years, months, and weeks are automatically rejected by `Duration#parse`.

```java
String input = "P2MT12H";
try
{
    Duration duration = Duration.parse( input );
}
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Faulty input." );
}
```

When run:

> ERROR - Faulty input.

Comment: This is the recommended way to do it in production code. **A note for the OP and other future visitors**: Do not use a regex (as suggested in the comments) as the solution to this problem, in production. However, you can try regex as the solution to this problem for learning and fun.

Comment: Isn't `PT25H` an invalid value? In the code this value is being parsed without any error message

Comment: @firstpostcommenter No, nothing wrong with an input of 25 hours. In a `Duration` that means one 24-hour day and one hour. A `Duration` represents a span of time in terms of hours-minutes-seconds-nanoseconds. I don’t know the maximum, but you can have [at least two billion hours](https://ideone.com/Nfs765).