# Conversion of UTC to IST time in java is working in LOCAL but not in CLOUD SERVER

Tags: java, date, timezone, server, cloud

I am working in date conversion in java in that i am using following code snippet to convert the UTC time to IST format.It is working properly in the local when i run it but when i deploy it in server its not converting , its displaying only the utc time itself.Is there any configuaration is needed in server side.Please help me out.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
   DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

    try {
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(utcDate);
        Date ISTDate = sdf.parse(formattedDate);
String ISTDateString = formatter.format(ISTDate);
            return ISTDateString;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "IST" (Indian standard time; Irish standard time; Israel standard time?); and what is the JVM's default timezone on the server?

Comment: What is the type of `utcDate`? I assume it is a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Your code never actually converts to IST, you literally set sdf to "UTC", and then just parse the formatted date.

Comment: Sorry i have update the code now check it i am getting ist time correctly with +5.30 conversion @Paddez and i mean ist as Indian Standard Time

Comment: Try using TimeZone set and get again as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14314481/2250010).

Comment: I am not so sure what you are trying to do. If you are trying to get IST time you should set the timezone to IST.
`sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));`

Comment: Thanks its worked i am setting the timezone of formatter to IST and the time as indian time perfectly from the server   formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

Comment: @Vicky, as shown in Andreas's answer, use `Asia/Kolkata`.  It is more correct than `IST`.

Comment: Ok thanks but is there any difference @MattJohnson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java `Date` objects are already/always in UTC. Time Zone is something that is applied when formatting to text. A `Date` cannot (should not!) be in any time zone other than UTC.

So, the entire concept of converting `utcDate` to `ISTDate` is flawed.
(BTW: Bad name. Java conventions says it should be `istDate`)

Now, if you want the code to return the date as text in IST time zone, then you need to request that:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")); // Or whatever IST is supposed to be
return formatter.format(utcDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Java 8 New API,

```
Instant s = Instant.parse("2019-09-28T18:12:17Z");
        ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
        LocalDateTime l = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(s, ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(l);
```