# How to compare Two date in android?

Tags: android, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have a date from server in the format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` .I have the current time in millis by `System.currentTimeMillis()`. I want to compare both dates and see if date received from server is future date and if it is so schedule an alarm for the future date.
so my question how to compare this 2 different format dates and how to get remaining time (future- current) so as to schedule the alarm.

Edit:
I already tried parsing the date in millis but it doesnt return value as same format as  `System.currentTimeMillis()`. so it fails

Comment: why was this marked as duplicate , that question doesn't address my concern of comparing two different date format

Comment: downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @tyczj how is this a duplicate?

Comment: because you can easily find how to convert a string datetime to milliseconds by searching

Comment: see my edit , i have a different issue

Comment: that edit does not make sense, currentTimeMilliseconds gives milliseconds and the string parsing returns a date which you can get milliseconds from

Comment: @tyczj the format returned by both in millis are different so comparison is not working

Comment: well why would they be the same, one is the current time the other is some other datetime. I still dont understand the problem

Comment: @tyczj i am converting the server date to millis and getting currenttimeinmillis from system method but the comparison is not proper , even if server date is after the current date it still return before

Comment: is the server date time in UTC if its not you need to set the timezone of the server time before you parse it

Comment: This has nothing to do with the discussion, but do you consider time zone in your code? E.g. in Tokio right now it's 11 march, 06:26 , while in Los Angeles it's 10 march, 13:26. If your code ignores timezone you can have mismatches

Comment: i tried setting UTC timezone to server date but output still the same

Comment: @user2340612 server time is UTC+5:30 INDIAN STANDARD TIME

Comment: @ankitagrawal ok so then that is what you have to set your timezone to in your code before you parse your date string

Comment: @tyczj df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); like this

Comment: Server time is UTF+5:30, but you can assume nothing for what concerns the device. This means that you should **also** retrieve the timezone from the device on which the app is running (this question [has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672597/how-to-get-timezone-from-android-mobile))

Comment: Lol I'm always late with comments! :)

Comment: @user2340612 i tried that also with no result , anyway i will post my code as soon as i am my machine and also try your suggestion maybe i am missing something silly

Comment: Read this link how to set the timezone before you parse

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314426/how-to-parse-date-from-gmt-timezone-to-ist-timezone-and-vice-versa-in-android

Comment: If you compare the millis from current to the parse, there will always be differences because the parsed time has milliseconds as 000. You can divide both time in millis by 1000 and compare that.

Comment: @tyczj solved issue was hh instead of HH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can parse the `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` date thanks to `DateFormat` class (e.g. the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class). This operation will return a `Date` object.

You can also create a `Date` object from current time in milliseconds.

When you have both objects you can compare them thanks to `compareTo` method.

For instance the following code:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date parsed = sdf.parse("2016-03-10 22:05:20");

    Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); // 2016-03-10 22:06:10

    System.out.println(parsed.compareTo(now));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

will print `-1`, which means that `parsed` is **before** `now`.

### EDIT:

Here it is the code of a simple but useless application that makes use of AlarmManager.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.d("TAG", "From intent: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("MyEXTRA"));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        long parsedMillis = sdf.parse("2016-03-10 22:54:30").getTime();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); // 22:54:15

        if (parsedMillis > now) {
            Log.d("TAG", "In the future!");

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MyEXTRA", "From alarm");
            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, parsedMillis, broadcast);

        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "In the past...");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the LogCat you will see:

```
03-10 22:54:20.925    3946-3946/com.example.myapp D/TAG﹕ From intent: null
03-10 22:54:21.227    3946-3946/com.example.myapp D/TAG﹕ In the future!
03-10 22:54:30.513    3946-3946/com.example.myapp D/TAG﹕ From intent: From alarm
03-10 22:54:30.577    3946-3946/com.example.myapp D/TAG﹕ In the past...
```

The last line is printed because the alarm causes the activity to be relaunched, hence the `onResume` will be called another time and `System.currentTimeMillis()` will be greater than the hardcoded time. As you can see, however, the alarm is correctly fired at the scheduled time.

Moreover you should consider edge cases: if `parsedMillis` is greater than `now` by only a few milliseconds, you could set an alarm that will never be fired because it is set in the past. This happens because the OS needs some time to execute your code, so you should check that `parsedMillis > now + DELTA`, where `DELTA` is a reasonable amout of time that depends on the code you execute between `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `am.setExact(...)`.

Comment: what about getting the time difference in millis to schedule an alarm

Comment: Well you can call `parsed.getTime()` to get the time in milliseconds. After that it's just a matter of math..

Comment: i tried setExact but not working, can u post some code that works in alarmManager

Comment: You should check if `parsed` is in the future or not (by comparing it to `System.currentTimeMillis()`). If it is in the future and you want to trigger the alarm at that time you should use `parsed.getTime()` as `triggerAtMillis` parameter of `alarmManager.setExact(...)` method.

Comment: i solved it , it was just a HH issue i was hh that it why time was wrong, since u helped you , i accepted the answer

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you do it using the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

A simple way to do it using the modern API is to parse the server's date-time string into `ZonedDateTime` using the server's timezone and convert the resulting object into [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) which you can compare with `Instant#now`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An arbitrary date for demo
        String strDateTime = "2021-05-09 10:20:30";

        // Replace JVM's default time zone, ZoneId.systemDefault() with applicable time
        // zone e.g. ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        Instant instantServer = zdt.toInstant();
        Instant now = Instant.now();

        if (instantServer.isBefore(now))
            System.out.println("The server time is before the current time.");
        else if (instantServer.isAfter(now))
            System.out.println("The server time is after the current time.");
        else
            System.out.println("The server time is the same as the current time.");
    }
}
```

**Output when I run it now in my system:**

```
The server time is before the current time.
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>