# Java time zone format issue

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, datetime-format, timezone-offset

The saved time in the application is in UTC. The users of the application are in different timezones, such as PST, IST etc.

My issue is very similar to the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java). 
I tried implementing a solution provided there, but it does not seem to be working for me:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(history.getCreatedTimestamp());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

//Here you say to java the initial timezone. This is the secret
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
//Will print in UTC
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

//Here you set to your timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
//Will print on your default Timezone
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: Why are you converting an existing value into a string and then parsing it again? That's almost always a bad idea. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem - there's a lot that's missing here.

Comment: Additionally, it's not clear what you expect `ZoneOffset.ofHours(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)` to do, but that's basically wrong. `Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET` is a constant - surely you want to use the user's actual time zone, which is unlikely to be a `ZoneOffset` anyway. "PST" isn't a time zone - it's an ambiguous abbreviation for *part* of when a time zone is observed. You'll need to know the user's actual time zone ID, e.g. America/New_York - or use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` if your code is running on the user's machine - it's unclear from your question.

Comment: no, the code will run in a server located in PST.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314481/5624464 refer this answer

Comment: Well, probably located in Pacific Time... but anyway, that suggests you need to get the user's time zone from somewhere. Do you have that? (Additionally, please take more care when presenting code. Use the preview to see what we'll see when it's posted, and ask yourself whether that's the best presentation in terms of indexing etc.)

Comment: Yes looks like there is no way to do it wihout getting the timeZone. Currently i do not have it at server context. Thanks will be diligent enough in future.

Comment: Depending on your architecture there may be [an interesting answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602679/5772882) about getting a browser’s time zone — in case you are doing a web app.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use Java 8 classes (`SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` [are trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265), avoid them if possible):

```
long timestamp = history.getCreatedTimestamp();
// create Instant from timestamp value
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);

// formatter
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

// convert to UTC
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)));

// convert to another timezone
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))));

// convert to JVM default timezone
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

Unfortunately, short zone names like PST and IST are ambiguous (check [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)), so you need to translate them to [IANA's names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (which are the standard used by Java, such as `America/Los_Angeles` or `Europe/London`).

More about timezones: https://codeofmatt.com/2015/02/07/what-is-a-time-zone

Comment: Fine, though change **hh** to **HH** for 24 instead of 12 hours; which seems to be an error in the question.

Comment: @JoopEggen Done!

Comment: Well explained answer, thanks, but obviously cannot solve the issue that the OP doesn’t know the client time zone on the server.